# How can I authenticate users in OpenLDAP using multiple password schemes?

Tags: linux, openldap

I've seen this [Multiple OUs](https://serverfault.com/questions/705743/authenticating-users-in-openldap-from-multiple-ous) question, as well as the [*NO*](https://serverfault.com/questions/705743/authenticating-users-in-openldap-from-multiple-ous) post, but without a good explanation it doesn't really solve the problem.

I want to be able to allow users to authenticate using standard passwords when on the LAN (OpenLDAP *userPassword* **{SHA1}...** attribute), but also allow some to authenticate with OpenVPN over a SASL Passthrough where the userPassword attribute is set using **{SASL}**`user@realm`.  The OpenVPN server is setup with an LDAP base of `OU=vpnpeople,dc=corp,dc=com` so it's not possible for people to authenticate using their LAN password.

What I've come up with is a slightly problematic method of copying the user in `OU=people,dc=corp,com` to `OU=vpnpeople,dc=corp,com` and setting the userPassword attribute to **{SASL}**`user@realm`.

I was quite pleased with this solution until I realized that every application on the LAN using an LDAP search base of `dc=corp,dc=com` now has to either exclude the `OU=vpnpeople..` or explicitly list the allowed OUs from which a user can authenticate... ugh...

So, back to the drawing board. What's a good way to use multiple authentication methods for the same person in OpenLDAP?

**UPDATE** re: ACL

where 10.1.1.2 would be the vpn server...

```
access to dn.subtree="OU=vpnpeople,dc=example,dc=com"
    by peername.ip=10.1.1.2 anonymous read
    by * none
```

Comment: Why can't you do one user one password? As far as the LDAP clients are concerned {SHA1} {SSHA} {SASL} and {CLEARTEXT} all operate the same way.

Comment: The SASL passthrough goes to another server which authenticates users via software tokens (WiKID) for VPN access.  Once connected to the VPN, users access resources via their LAN password.  Both of these users/passwords are housed in the OpenLDAP servers but the VPN searchbase starts at 'ou=vpnpeople' so the LAN password will not work for VPN access. This could easily be solved by standing up an LDAP server just for VPN access, but that seems like using a mallet as a fly swatter.

Comment: I will rephrase. What do you hope to achieve by giving users two different accounts/passwords? If you're just trying to limit who can use VPN there's you can put additional requirements on the user such as belonging to a certain group or having a certain attribute set.

Comment: What I want is to allow users into the VPN using a password that is different than their LAN password. I think this means duplicating the users in a second OU (vpnpeople) with a completely different *userPassword* attribute. Then have the VPN server set it's ldap searchbase to OU=vpnpeople,... instead of the root of the ldap tree. Yes, I could limit users to only a certain ObjectClass or group, but then they would still be using their LAN password to get in. Which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an ACL entry on the ou=vpnpeople,dc=corp,dc=com subtree that allows only admin and the service account that the vpn server uses to access it.

Comment: Ah, nice! Hadn't thought of that. Not too familiar with ACLs, but managed to build a possibility (see UPDATE to original post above). Will that work? Not sure I want *dn.subtree* or *dn.children*

Comment: Either should be fine, there's likely no danger in the OU entry itself being read. However, you'll also want to allow your admin and replication DNs to be able to write and read, respectively. Unless you're doing something earlier to grant them unfettered access.